# How to deal with "lack of experience" situation?

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

Few weeks after the interview, one of the interviewers suggested that I'm still in the pool but the hiring manager is reposting the job and trying to look for someone with more experience. Should I do something to change the situation or keep waiting for the result from HM(highly likely a rejection) and move on?

Update: The recruiter, who never replied my email for an update, invites me or someone I know to apply the same position I interviewed for via linkedin. I understand I'm their back up plan and she has no power in the decision making process, but it is unprofessional in my opinion. Should I let her know or just simply ignore this?

Comment: **"Should I do something to change the situation?"** - What could yo do? Gain the experience? It's probably best to move on. There will be other opportunities for you.

Comment: To passively _'Keep Waiting'_ is not in your best interest, proactively make use of your time in the meanwhile by searching for new opportunities (because that ship has most likely sailed off) as well as interview preparation - good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should I do something to change the situation or keep waiting for the result from HM(highly likely a rejection) and move on?

For this specific situation there is nothing that you can do other than wait for the result.  If they want someone with more experience you will not be able to magically add experience to your qualifications.

Regardless, you should still be applying to and interviewing with other companies if you are in search of a new job.

Answer (score 4):

Right now, you are somebody's backup plan.

Don't be so available. Interview with other companies. If you get another offer, be sure to let the first company know.

Answer (score 1):

Let me put it this way: **"You are right now a** ***sales(wo)man!"***

(I might add: *"a perfectly honorable profession!!")*

So:  is it right now in your best interests to "put your wares in front of just one customer, and hope for the best?"  Of course not – **because "what you [and, you alone(!)] have to offer to the market** ***is(!)*** **valuable!"**

Therefore, like every salesperson before you, "spread *awareness* far and wide!"  Let every person who might be *very eager to(!)* "buy your product" be informed of their grand opportunity as soon as possible.

--- **And, by the way:  "I am utterly serious."**  *"Sales"* is inherently a multi-stage process, and right now, stage one, you are "looking for *prospects."*

Answer (score 1):

I would make a follow up email, if you haven't already. Something to the effect of:

> X, Thank you so much for the follow up. I understand that you are looking for someone with more experience. I want to say that while I do not have the resume experience, I am a quick learning. For example, look at what I did at X, or Y, or Z. I believe these samples will prove that I am ready for the job. I appreciate your time and I want you to know that I am interested in this job.

That's it. Then after hitting that send button, just continue on with the job hunt. If you hear back, then consider it at that time especially if you have other offers in hand or not.